# LDAP query invalid characters

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm getting stuck with formatting an LDAP query against my AD. It appears that the '+' character is messing up my life.

the following query works fine for me:

```
//C# AD lookup

DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry(
    "LDAP://mydomain/CN=group name that works,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=us");
```

but when I attempt to look up a group that has the '+' character in it:

```
//C# AD Lookup failure with '+' in CN

DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry(
    "LDAP://mydomain/CN=name+ thatFails,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=us");
```

I get a 'Invalid dn syntax has been specified' exception.

I've passed a bunch of valid group names with all sorts of 'special' chars suchas '_' and '&' which work. it appears that the '+' character is what is causing my grief. how do I format my CN correctly to make my query valid?

**EDIT**

as suggested, I escaped the '+' char. This unfortunately did not help. below is my current ldap format:

```
LDAP://mydomain/cn=_bigGroup\+ management office,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=us
```

Comment: Did you use double backslashes in your code, or use the literal string operator? e.g. new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mydomain/cn=_bigGroup\\+ management office,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=us") or new 
DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://mydomain/cn=_bigGroup\+ management office,OU=Groups,DC=myDomain,DC=us"

I believe it needs to be an actual backslash character, not an escape character in a C# string

Comment: see my updated answer below.  If you put an actual backslash character ('\\') before the escaped character it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you need to escape some characters with a backslash, see the list **[her](http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm)e**

**Update:**

The backslash does in fact work.  I created a new user object with cn='Escape+Test' in my local ADAM instance (hosted on port 9389).  I wrote a small Windows Forms program with the following code:

```
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://localhost:9389/CN=Escape\\+Test,OU=MyUsers Users,DC=TEST,DC=LOCAL", "test", "xxxx", AuthenticationTypes.None))
{
     MessageBox.Show(entry.Properties["cn"][0].ToString());
}
```

The program displayed "Escape+Test" when I ran it.

Notice the double backslashes to represent an actual backslash and not an escape character.  I would expect the same behavior on a full AD domain.

Just as a sanity check I replaced the backslash with %2B as mentioned by another answer and when I did I got a "no such object on the server" error when trying to access the entry's properties.

Comment: @EJP - Yes it works.  Your suggestion does not.  When I replace the backslash with %2B it responds with "no such object on the server" when I try to access the entry's properties.

Answer (score -1):

Connecting to LDAP is  possible for specific users only , hence we need to specify the group of users that has access to the LDAP and define them in the Application Pool.
When we are creating a new website add this app pool which has the access rights ,
Unless until u provide  a correct application pool, we will get this type of errors.